# Flask before_request and teardown_request for DB connections

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask, psycopg2, flask-sqlalchemy

According to the Flaskr tutorial, db connection should be opened and closed before each session:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
  g.db = connect_db()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
  db = getattr(g, 'db', None)
  if db is not None:
    db.close()
```

However, this is the case when using sqlite3.

my question is: when using postressql and SqlAlchemy - do connections need to be opened and closed in the same way, or does SQLAlchemy takes care of connection management automatically?

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy manages a DB connection pool for you, so you don't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: thanks Miguel. to follow-up: does one need to explicitly define an _init_ constructor for the model when using sqlalchemy & postgres? in your mega-tutorial you do not use one, but when I omit the __init__ I get a "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)" error.

Comment: SQLAlchemy also provides a default constructor for your model. This default constructor takes `**kwargs` that initialize the attributes of the model. I don't understand why you get the `TypeError`, look in the stack trace to see where is this `__init__()` constructor that takes one argument, that is not the type of constructor that SQLAlchemy defines.

Answer (score 3):

SQLAlchemy doesn't know about your Flask application. So, if you want to use pure SQLAlchemy you need to manage connections.

Dealing with these topics by yourself without enough knowledge on db connections, persistent connections and connection pooling may lead to very poor performance and errors.
Best practice is to use [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) to abstract db connection management.