# Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a small website and I already have **all** my models in SQLAlchemy. The website is to publish some information from some calculations which are done offline. Only the results will be published to a slimmed down database i.e. it contains the results, not the raw data, but the website needs to query the results.

I'm going to use Flask, as my models are already driven with Python (and some heavy lifting in C++ via SWIG) and I don't want to use Django.

Now this has been asked before I'm sure and the usual mantra without much justification is to 'use Flask-SQLAlchemy'. The question is why?

If I write some session handling myself, why do I have to go through the additional layer of redefining my database in Flask-SQLAlchemy. Other than having to write some code like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457667/flask-before-request-and-teardown-request-for-db-connections) in my Flask app somewhere:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
  g.db = connect_db()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
  db = getattr(g, 'db', None)
  if db is not None:
    db.close()
```

What else do I need to worry about? SQLAlchemy even does connection pooling for me by default.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you are building a web application using `Flask` which do database related kinds of stuff by `sqlalchemy`. So, when you are dealing with database **session** with multiple requests which your application handles, then you have to ascertain that, you are creating and closing sessions cautiously.

If you read **SQLAlchemy** [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it), they recommend to keep the lifecycle of the session separate and external from functions and objects that access and/or manipulate database data. This will greatly help with achieving a predictable and consistent transactional scope.

> A web application is the easiest case because such an application is already constructed around a single, consistent scope - this is the `request`, which represents an incoming request from a browser, the processing of that request to formulate a response, and finally the delivery of that response back to the client. Integrating web applications with the `Session` is then the straightforward task of linking the scope of the `Session` to that of the request. The `Session` can be established as the request begins, or using a lazy initialization pattern which establishes one as soon as it is needed. The request then proceeds, with some system in place where application logic can access the current Session in a manner associated with how the actual request object is accessed. As the request ends, the `Session` is torn down as well, usually through the usage of event hooks provided by the web framework. The transaction used by the Session may also be committed at this point, or alternatively the application may opt for an explicit commit pattern, only committing for those requests where one is warranted, but still always tearing down the `Session` unconditionally at the end.

In laymen terms, i mean to say that

> In `SQLAlchemy`, above action is mentioned because sessions in web application should be **scoped**, meaning that each request handler creates and destroys its own session.
>
> This is necessary because web servers can be multi-threaded, so multiple requests might be served at the same time, each working with a different database session.

This means that if you are using **SqlAlchemy** with **Flask**, you have to manually handle session like creating `scoped session` and also remove them on each request  cautiously otherwise you may be in deep shit, which adds extra layer of complexity to your web application.

But, there comes `Flask-SqlAlchemy` (an extension of **sqlalchemy** library for `Flask` app) which provides infrastructure to assist in the task of aligning the lifespan of a `Session` with that of each web request. Actually, you can also found that in **SqlAlchmey** [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it), they also recommend to use this with `Flask`.

**Flask-SQLAlchemy** creates a fresh/new `scoped session` for each request. If you dig further it you will find out here, it also installs a hook on `app.teardown_appcontext` (for Flask >=0.9), `app.teardown_request` (for Flask 0.7-0.8), `app.after_request` (for Flask <0.7) and here is where it calls `db.session.remove()`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you put in the question is not actually valid for Sqlalchemy integration is Flask. I know it is just example, but saying that just in case.

For Sqlalchemy integration all you need to do is to make sure current  `DbSession` is cleaned up at the end of request via something like this:

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    DbSession.remove()
```

where DbSession is [scoped session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/contextual.html#thread-local-scope).

[Here is documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/patterns/sqlalchemy/#declarative) for the case when you dont want to use Flask-Sqlalchemy package.